# Pass a string to for WHERE clause in stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to pass a string from a text box in my stored procedure for a `WHERE` clause, basically what I want to do is this.

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE "Textbox1.text" = '1234'
```

(the textbox value will be the column name(ex. 'ID')

How can I do that in a stored procedure?

Here's what I done so far, it returns no value

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE ORProc
    @SEARCH_PARAMETER VARCHAR(100) = NULL,
    @OR_NUMBER VARCHAR(20) = NULL,
    @CLIENT_NAME VARCHAR(100) = NULL,
    @OR_DATE VARCHAR(10) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT * 
    FROM OR_HEADER 
    WHERE '%'+ @SEARCH_PARAMETER + '%' = @OR_NUMBER 
       OR '%'+ @SEARCH_PARAMETER + '%' = @OR_DATE 
       OR '%'+ @SEARCH_PARAMETER + '%' = @CLIENT_NAME
 END;

 EXEC ORProc @SEARCH_PARAMETER = 'OR_NUMBER',
             @OR_NUMBER = '23232'
```

Comment: use LIKE instead of =

Comment: Perhaps you can find something of value [here](https://www.sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/) or [here](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html).

Comment: Rather than pass the column name from the application, I suggest you build and execute a dynamic query in the stored proc with only the needed columns specified in the WHERE clause. See [Dynamic Search Conditions](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try the next query

```
SELECT * 
FROM OR_HEADER 
WHERE (@SEARCH_PARAMETER='OR_NUMBER' AND OR_NUMBER=@OR_NUMBER)
  OR (@SEARCH_PARAMETER='OR_DATE' AND OR_DATE=@OR_DATE)
  OR (@SEARCH_PARAMETER='CLIENT_NAME' AND CLIENT_NAME=@CLIENT_NAME)
```

And I think you can replace `@OR_DATE VARCHAR(10) = NULL` to `@OR_DATE DATE = NULL` or `@OR_DATE DATETIME = NULL`.

I think you can replace three value parameters to one `@SEARCH_VALUE`

```
ALTER PROCEDURE ORProc
    @SEARCH_PARAMETER VARCHAR(100) = NULL,
    @SEARCH_VALUE VARCHAR(100) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF(ISNULL(@SEARCH_PARAMETER,'') NOT IN('','ID','OR_NUMBER','OR_DATE','CLIENT_NAME'))
    BEGIN
      PRINT 'You sent the wrong parameter!'
      RETURN
    END

    SELECT * 
    FROM OR_HEADER 
    WHERE (@SEARCH_PARAMETER='OR_NUMBER' AND OR_NUMBER=@SEARCH_VALUE)
      OR (@SEARCH_PARAMETER='OR_DATE' AND OR_DATE=CAST(@SEARCH_VALUE AS date))
      OR (@SEARCH_PARAMETER='CLIENT_NAME' AND CLIENT_NAME=@SEARCH_VALUE)
      OR (@SEARCH_PARAMETER='ID' AND ID=CAST(@SEARCH_VALUE AS int))
      OR ISNULL(@SEARCH_PARAMETER,'')=''

END
```